# Connect to a SSH server trough a corporate proxy

Tags: router, ssh, proxy

I have an SSH server running on port 443 at home and I was able to connect from my office trough our corporate proxy using the same 443 port.

Problem is, I have changed my internet service and I can´t forward port 443 in the new router. Maybe the new company is using it for remote access or it is blocked by default. The only way to get out from the office is 443.

Is there any way to redirect it to another port in my router? Any other idea?

Edit 1: Added a little scheme:

Office PC -->Corporate proxy -->Home router -->SSH server

Comment: Windows / Linux / Mac ?

Comment: SSH server is in a Linux machine and i connect from a Windows machine using Putty

Comment: Why can't you parameter the SSH server to listen on another port? And which server are you using?

Comment: The problem is not the internal port where SSH is listening, it is the external port that i try to forward to the internal one. I can forward any other external port to the internal one, but i need the external port to be 443 cause it is the only one i can reach from my office trough the corporate proxy. Sorry if i am not making it clear and thanks for the reply.

Comment: You can change it to port 80 and no corporate proxy will touch it.

Comment: i am getting the same problem with port 80. It seems they are blocked by my company or the router itself. When i use [port check tool](http://www.portchecktool.com/) to check these ports, it says "connection timed out", on the other hand, if i check any ohter port that i have not forwarded, it says "connection refused".

Comment: Must be your router. Do you control it, and what is it?

Comment: I think that too. I can log in, forward ports and i have set firewall to Low, but i can´t find any config related to these ports (80 or 443). I guess my internet company has hide or block some configurations. By the way, the router is a sagemcom f@st 5655v2AC and there is barely no info in the company website, no manual, nothing useful.

Comment: The router web-gui probably use those ports. I once had to change my router's web interface to use 8080 and 8443 before I could forward those ports to another computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i find myself the solution. As @svin83 has pointed out, the router is using ports 80 (HTTP) and 443 (HTTPS) for remote access, so we need to disable that option if we want to reach these ports. To be able to do this, we need to log in as admin on the router, in my case, a Sagemcom Fast 5655v2AC.
By default, the internet company has disabled the admin user, so i have to reset the router to factory defaults. I follow the instructions on this post https://bandaancha.eu/foros/extraer-gpon-router-sagemcom-fast-5655v2-1731346 to do that. By now, we can log in with the admin user.
In the main window, we move to "**access control**", then "**remote access**" and under "**Remote management**" there are the two options HTTP and HTTPS, turn on by default. Now, we can turn off one or both options to unblock their respective ports.
Finally, we connect again the fiber cable and test that everything is working. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find a manual to a similar model, written by a frustrated user :
[SAGEMCOM FST 5355](https://crowdsupport.telstra.com.au/t5/Modems-Hardware/Sagemcon-F-st-5355-Manual/td-p/643374).

That model does support port forwarding, and the relevant two pages are below :

---

[image: page1]

---

[image: page22]

Comment: I have already seen it but it doesn't address the issue. I can forward any port except 80 or 443.

Comment: I might be missing something : Why can't you use another port? Could you also detail how you are prevented from using ports 80 and 443.

Comment: sorry if i am not making myself clear. I can only use port 443 cause is the only port i can go trough my corporate proxy. So, in my home router, i have to forward  external port 443 to the port where i am running ssh server, that's also 443. I can connect from inside my network, so shh is running fine. If i open another port and forward it to ssh server, i can connect from, i.e. my mobile phone. In fact, i can't connect to myhost.com:443 from any device.

Comment: Just edited the question to add a little scheme.

Comment: The problem really seems without solution, if you can only use two ports that are blocked by your router. I suggest to get in touch with your ISP - maybe a firmware update exists that solves the problem, maybe you could ask for another model router. If not, the only solutions I can think of are using some intermediate server between your company and your router, or getting your own router/modem.